# Can't read Amazon S3 Object meta-data using .Net API, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I've read the S3 documentation several times and I'm adding metadata to an S3 object with this code...

```
PutObjectRequest titledRequest = new PutObjectRequest();
titledRequest.WithTimeout(3600000)
.WithMetaData("outputfolder", outputFolder)
.WithBucketName(AWS_BUCKET_NAME)
.WithKey(objectKey)
.WithAutoCloseStream(true)
.WithInputStream(fs);
```

When reading the object from the S3 bucket I'm using this code....

```
string outputFolder = response.Metadata["x-amz-meta-outputfolder"];
```

But I'm getting an empty string every time even though the outputFolder variable definitely has a value.

Am I doing something really silly wrong here? As far as I can tell this is consistent with the documentation

Answer (score 1):

```
string outputFolder = response.Metadata["outputfolder"];
```

will do.

Answer (score 0):

use this instead of reading the meta from putobject response

```
GetObjectMetadataRequest request = new GetObjectMetadataRequest()
                    .WithKey("Key")
                    .WithBucketName("");
GetObjectMetadataResponse response = s3Client.GetObjectMetaData(request);
response."choose properety to retrieve"
```

hope this may help

Answer (score 0):

Codes verified to work.

```
// upload & add outputfolder to metadata

var S3Client = new AmazonS3Client();

var Request = new PutObjectRequest {
                  BucketName = bucketname,Key = S3Name,FilePath = Filepath };

Request.Metadata.Add("outputfolder",@"C:\test");

PutObjectResponse Response = S3Client.PutObject(Request);

// download and retrieve metadata

var S3Client = new AmazonS3Client();

var Request = new GetObjectRequest { BucketName = bucketname,Key = S3Name };

GetObjectResponse Response = S3Client.GetObject(Request);

// this works

string outputFolder = Response.Metadata["x-amz-meta-outputfolder"];

// so does this - no need for the x-amz-meta- prefix

string outputFolder = Response.Metadata["outputfolder"];
```